# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting this

Tags: java, coderunner

Why am i getting the exception error

va.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting thisva.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException why am i getting this

```
}
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong because what you wrote is not doing what you think it does. You can't just type random stuff and expect it to work, there are very strict rules in order for code to compile.

Comment: The reason your code still compiles is that you compare `chr` with the result of a mathematical substraction. `char`s can be used in mathematical operations. `'a'-'z'` is `97-122` which results in `-25`.

Comment: The question means something else than you think.  The wording indicates a range - your code describes a subtraction (which for historical reasons is valid Java). If you have learned about regular expressions I would expect one to be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `'a'-'z'` which will convert into ASCII code subtraction and the result will be `-25`, and as for your `'A'-'Z'` statement, the result will be (well, also) `-25`.

You should write something like

```
if( (chr <= 'z' && chr >= 'a') || (chr <= 'Z' && chr >= 'A') )
    return true;
return false;
```

Always remember, that computers work with **ASCII codes**, rather than "characters", and the computer will check for the **valid code** of given characters (which are **always** positive, `-25` is not valid), in our case, the ASCII code of `chr` SHOULD be smaller-or-equal to `z`, and so on (see the if-statement above).

If you are familiar with overloading the `return` statement, you could also simplify your function (make it more readable):

```
return (chr >= 'a' && chr <= 'z') || (chr >= 'A' && chr <= 'Z')
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `if(chr == 'a'-'z')` is not correct. `'a'` and `'z'` are both character literals, but in Java a character is a 16-bit integral type. So `'a'-'z'` is a long way to write `-25`. I would simplify the logic and the test. Something like

```
public static boolean isValidChar_Q1(char chr) {
    char t = Character.toLowerCase(chr);
    return t >= 'a' && t <= 'z';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your comparisons you're trying to compare a single char to a range, which is something you cannot write like that in Java. That syntax of yours looks closer to a regex (`[a-zA-Z]`) than a proper Java comparison.

If you want to check whether a variable's value is within a range, you need to compare it with its boundaries: greater than or equal to the left edge and lower than or equal to the right edge.

```
public static boolean isValidChar_Q1(char chr) {
    return (chr >= 'a' && chr <= 'z') || (chr >= 'A' && chr <= 'Z');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Regex:

```
import java.util.regex. * ;

    boolean isMatch = Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]", "S");
```